# Navigation bar only appears on page 1 , the other no longer appears

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I resumed my project and got the following storybard

[image: StoryBoard]

And in CollectionViewController i have the following code, my problem is when i call the other pages, the navigation bar dissapears

```
<pre> - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //navigation bar
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    [backButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button2;
    self.title = @"Welcome User";

    marrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    mdictImageData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"circlshadow_parking.png",@"imageFile",@"Parking",@"Info",nil];
    [marrImages addObject:mdictImageData];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
    if(lastIndex == 0)
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *myVC = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ParkingMenu"];
        myVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:myVC animated:YES];  
    }
}<code>
```

Comment: Show us your storyboard. Show us screen shots. Tell us how you move from one page to another. Tell us how you "return home".

Comment: My storyboard is http://s30.postimg.org/srmobz201/Captura_de_Tela_2015_12_07_s_16_18_05.png and i call the pages like this  UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ParkingMenu"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];   because i have a collection view controller

Comment: Please edit your question to add the details.

Comment: Also let us know what is the origin of the segues visible on the storyboard.

Comment: And where in your code (which method of which class) you have the code quoted.

Comment: I decided to start the project again and embed the navigation bar and apparently is working the problem is that when I call the second page I get the following error "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <CollectionViewController: 0x12c53fe50>."

Comment: You should not need to add a navigation bar, it's provided by your navigation controller.

Comment: If I do not embeb the navigationBar she does not show,

Comment: You have not answered to many of the questions above. Also, if you have restarted from scratch, please provide the updated information (storyboard, details of segues including origin and type, etc.).

Comment: Ok, i´m sorry. I´m new in ios programming. Now i have this storyBoard [link](http://s29.postimg.org/8wt8mf0sn/Captura_de_Tela_2015_12_09_a_s_16_54_15.png). and i call the second page using this code    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ParkingMenu"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];   
apparently the page is being called 2 times

Comment: Again, please update the question with the new storyboard link and the new code. Also, you still haven't given us the details of the segues in your storyboard (where they originate at, their type (it's too small to identify on your picture)), or where (class and method) you "call the second page". Given that you have segues in your storyboard, you probably should not need to to instantiate view controllers yourself.

Comment: Also, when you reply to a comment, please quote who you are replying to (@ + username, you'll get auto-completion), so they can be notified.

Comment: @jcaron it is possible talk with you in private? thank you

Comment: Yes, but I would have to charge for it, and my rates are quite high...

Comment: @jcaron oo ok , it is that here I can not put pictures and my code in a decent way for you to understand my problem.

Comment: You definitely can, others manage to do it. Remember, update your question rather than trying to add code in comments.

Comment: Ok, i edit my question. thanks @jcaron

Answer (score 0):

Based on the setup of your Storyboard, you really should be using segues rather than manually instantiating and presenting a view controller.

Based on the blurry icon in your storyboard screenshot, it looks like you've successfully set these up as "Show" segues.  There's a small chance that your problem lies elsewhere, but this certainly moves you to the more "standard" and best practice oriented way of doing things.

To correct this, set a segue identifier on the segue between Collection View Controller and the Parking Menu View Controller.  Let's assume that segue is identified as "ParkingMenuSegue."  Then, when you need to present that, use:

**Objective-C:**

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ParkingMenuSegue" sender:sender];
```

**Swift:**

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier("ParkingMenuSegue", sender: nil)
```